# Magento 2.4.3 index issue - Deadlock

Tags: reindex, magento2.4.3, deadlock

We are experiencing some major issues with reindex lately. We think it has something to do with the 3rd party module (we can't turn it off) We get deadlock during re-indexing every day.

And ofc that causes tons of issues.

The error we get is:

[image]

Does anyone know what these say and what the issue might be?

The issue we have with the payment is:
The customer chose the payment method, and get "something went wrong please try again" but the customer still gets charged and the order is created in the 3rd part console and nothing in Magento. But suddenly it shows up in Magento after 15/20 min. Very strange behavior.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, but the order didn't appears even after 15/20 mins. Order failed to create.
If you will find some solution mention that here

Comment: What payment provider do you use?